# Permission Denied When using XMLHttpRequest.Open cross browser access

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access XMLHTTPRequest.open Method I have even included netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");

but still its not working.

I am using javascript and HTML to access the WebService.

Any Help would be really great

Code

<html>
  <Head> 
    <Title>Calling A WebService from HTML </Title>
  </Head>

<Body onload='GetDataFrmWS()'>
  <form name="Form1" id="Form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <div id="DisplayData" > </div>
    <div id="Menu2"></div>

</form>

<script language='javascript'>

var objHttp;
var objXmlDoc;

function GetDataFrmWS()
{
  alert('I M Here');
  var func = getDataFromWS();

}

function getDataFromWS()
{

if(window.ActiveXObject)
  {
     try 
        {
        objHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');

```
    }
 catch (ex)
 {
  objHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }
```

}
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
 {
   objHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
 }

strEnvelope = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
'<soap:Body>' +
'  <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
'     <Dummy xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello</Dummy>'+
'  </HelloWorld>'+
'</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>' ;

var szUrl;
szUrl = 'http://kamadhenu/Quoteme/GetCategories.asmx?op=HelloWorld';
objHttp.onreadystatechange = HandleResponse;

objHttp.open('POST', szUrl, true);
objHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
objHttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction','http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld');
objHttp.send(strEnvelope);

}

function HandleResponse()
{
if (objHttp.readyState == 4) 
 {

if (window.ActiveXObject)
   {
     objXmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     objXmlDoc.async="false";
     objXmlDoc.loadXML(objHttp.responseText);
     var nodeSelect = objXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Menu1").item(0);
     var Menu2=objXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Menu2").item(0);
     document.getElementById('DisplayData').innerHTML=nodeSelect.text;
     document.getElementById('Menu2').innerHTML=Menu2.text; 
    }
  else
   {
    var Text=objHttp.responseText;
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    objXmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(Text,'text/xml');
    var Value=objXmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var Menu2=objXmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var Menu3=objXmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('DisplayData').innerHTML=Value;
    document.getElementById('Menu2').innerHTML=Menu2; 
    document.getElementById('Menu2').innerHTML+=Menu3; 
   }
 }

}

</script>
  <input type='Button' Text='Click Me' onclick='GetDataFrmWS()' value="Click Me!"/>
  °
</Body>
</HTML>

Comment: Need to see formatted code rather, use the four-space indent so its readable...

Comment: I hope now the code is readble

Answer (score 2):

### Browser Independent code for XML HTTPRequest

I use the following code to create an XML object. It has been designed to handle all browsers (esp. IE and non IE)

```
/* Function to create an XMLHTTP object for all browsers */
function getXMLHTTPObject(){
    var xmlHttp;
    try{
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}       
/* End Function */
```

P.S. You code in the question is not readable. Pls format it

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty concise example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceFromHTMLPage.aspx)

Try making your URL http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/Jobs.asmx/InsertXML

PS. Your code is unreadable in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the XMLHTTP request must point to a page on the same subdomain of the html page for the various browsers permissions.

One trick is to make another page on the same server in your preferred language and make it handle the request with the server's network.

Example:

from your HTML page you make a ajax request to mydomain.com/externalrequest.php?url=www.google.com
and that page will connect (fsock/cURL etc) to "url" and return it

Answer (score 1):

If you are TRYING to go cross-domain with XHR, you can look into the JSONP method. Check JQuery docs for that.

Would require you to accept JSON response but it does work across domains.